# Implementation of FFT 2D array

Tags: c, 2d, fft

I'm using some C code currently to display evolution of solutions to the 1D Schrodinger equation using a Fourier method.

This method uses an FFT algorithm from Numerical Recipes in C to calculate the second derivative (in k space) in the equation from the function values in a 1D column array as part of the process.

I'd like to move into 2D solutions, which I guess would require a 2D array 'grid' for values of the function at those points.

My questions are these:

Can I still implement this same FFT on an NxN array? If so, how?

Would I need a different FFT algorithm?

Thanks.

The source code I'm using for the FFT is:

```
void four1(double data[], int nn, int isign)
{
    int n, mmax, m, j, istep, i;
    double wtemp, wr, wpr, wpi, wi, theta;
    double tempr, tempi;

    n = nn << 1;
    j = 1;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i += 2) {
    if (j > i) {
        tempr = data[j];     data[j] = data[i];     data[i] = tempr;
        tempr = data[j+1]; data[j+1] = data[i+1]; data[i+1] = tempr;
    }
    m = n >> 1;
    while (m >= 2 && j > m) {
        j -= m;
        m >>= 1;
    }
    j += m;
    }
    mmax = 2;
    while (n > mmax) {
    istep = 2*mmax;
    theta = TWOPI/(isign*mmax);
    wtemp = sin(0.5*theta);
    wpr = -2.0*wtemp*wtemp;
    wpi = sin(theta);
    wr = 1.0;
    wi = 0.0;
    for (m = 1; m < mmax; m += 2) {
        for (i = m; i <= n; i += istep) {
        j =i + mmax;
        tempr = wr*data[j]   - wi*data[j+1];
        tempi = wr*data[j+1] + wi*data[j];
        data[j]   = data[i]   - tempr;
        data[j+1] = data[i+1] - tempi;
        data[i] += tempr;
        data[i+1] += tempi;
        }
        wr = (wtemp = wr)*wpr - wi*wpi + wr;
        wi = wi*wpr + wtemp*wpi + wi;
    }
    mmax = istep;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can implement a 2D FFT by taking 1D FFTs of all the rows followed by 1D FFTs of the columns. You might want to look at 2D FFT libraries such as FFTW though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 1D FFT code are ready, you can construct the 2D FFT by Row-Column method, i.e., first perform the 1D FFT on each row then perform the 1D FFT on each column, or first perform the 1D FFT on each column then perform the 1D FFT on each row. This approach is based on the separable property of 2D FFT. Note that the 1D FFTs are in-place processing, that is, the data for the first 1D FFTs may be real type, but have become complex type for the second stage.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. I understand the procedure and seem to have made a 2D array now. Do you have any idea how to use the function I showed to operate only on one column or row of the 2D array so I implement the procedure?

Comment: Since the 2D array (note the complex type) is in row order, if you choose the first row then column scheme, the first each row 1D FFTs are easy; you need to just pass the address of each row and the length to the 1D FFT function, however, the following column FFTs are not ready; you can allocate a 1D array (note the complex type) with the size equal to the column length, copy the data of each colunmn into the array, perform the 1D FFT on the array data , and then copy the result back the column of the 2D array.